# Is it possible to get access of Google Analytics on a non-Google ID?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console

We are using the company mail address to get access to Google Analytic, Google webmaster and Google my business.

We are going to close our company mail address and open open new Microsoft accounts. Are we going to need a Google account to access previous services? or can we share the admin access to a non Google account?.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any email domain in all Google services as long as you use it as a **Google Account**. Check the following image: [image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, using Microsoft id we can able to login or not above tools.

Comment: Yes, as long as you have an email address and you create a Google Account with it

Comment: Some peoples opinion is you will need gmail account to access google products like web master tools and google analytics, so it is not a good idea to completely delete the gmail account, because with deleting it you can lose your webmaster tool and google analytics account.  So if we share the admin access to a microsoft id, we can able to access the tools in future.

Comment: At least GSC and Analytics have an "edit users" privilege to share so, it doesn't matter which email was the first to create the account as long as another one can grant admin access to other accounts.

Comment: Google says that you can delete your Gmail account without closing your entire Google account.  https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61177?&hl=en  Even without Gmail, you can log into other Google services including Google Analytics and Google Search Console.    As Emirodgar says, you can also sign up for Google services with an external email address.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your new Microsoft Email as an alternative Email. That way you can keep your current logins or can login with the new email and current password.

- Go to https://myaccount.google.com
- Check "Your Personal Info"
- Go to "Email" in the table on the right
- Add your new email address to "Alternative Emails"